# Plugin unable to load the image- Getting Unable to resolve plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

The plugin is unable to load the image file

```
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/com.softwareag.is.ui.stc.generateskeleton_9.12.0.0000-v1/icons/skeleton.png
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/com.softwareag.is.ui.stc.generateskeleton_9.12.0.0000-v1/icons/skeleton.png".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.find(FileLocator.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(AbstractUIPlugin.java:713)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardElement.getImageDescriptor(WorkbenchWizardElement.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.wizards.WizardShortcutAction.<init>(WizardShortcutAction.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.WizardActionGroup.getAction(WizardActionGroup.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.WizardActionGroup.findGroups(WizardActionGroup.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.WizardActionGroup.fillContextMenu(WizardActionGroup.java:205)
    at com.softwareag.is.ui.navigator.providers.ISActionProvider.fillContextMenu(ISActionProvider.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService$2.run(NavigatorActionService.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.addCommonActionProviderMenu(NavigatorActionService.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.fillContextMenu(NavigatorActionService.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager.fillContextMenu(CommonNavigatorManager.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.menuAboutToShow(CommonNavigatorManager.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.fireAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.handleAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.access$1(MenuManager.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager$2.menuShown(MenuManager.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1118)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_INITMENUPOPUP(Control.java:5037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1633)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2117)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5050)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.TrackPopupMenu(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu._setVisible(Menu.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runPopups(Display.java:4221)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

On the extension tab,

[image]

As seen clearly, the image is there but it doesn't appears in the New Wizard alongside the Plugin name

[image]

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: 0000-v1
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.softwareag.is.ui.stc.generateskeleton_9.12.0.0000-v1;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.softwareag.is.ui.stc.generateskeleton_91200000_v1.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: SOFTWAREAG
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 com.softwareag.is.core.iscomm;bundle-version="9.12.0",
 com.softwareag.is.ui.navigator;bundle-version="9.12.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/gson-2.8.6.jar,
 .
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plug-in id appears to be wrong. The id is the value of the `Bundle-SymbolicName` in the plug-in's MANIFEST.MF, it does not include the version information.

So the id is probably just `com.softwareag.is.ui.stc.generateskeleton`

Comment: Added details for MANIFEST.MF in the question.

Comment: The plugin was created with the name com.softwareag.is.ui.stc.generateskeleton_9.12.0.0000-v1. It shouldn't have any issue.

Comment: During the plugin creation process, as com.softwareag.is.ui.stc.generateskeleton_9.12.0.0000-v1 isn't the correct package name due to presence of dots, i inputted com.softwareag.is.ui.stc.generateskeleton_91200000_v1 as the package name.

Comment: Thanks greg. The plugin name isn't the correct one.

Comment: A slightly different version of the same question which I have raised separately[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918626/why-do-all-the-images-of-the-plugin-disappear-once-the-plugin-is-exported-as-a-j.) -  I am unable to get the images post export