# Why do all the images of the Plugin disappear once the plugin is exported as a jar and integrated in the IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

In my eclipse plugin, while testing the plugin(**Run As Eclipse Application**)-

As seen below, all the images in the New Wizard are rendered properly, highlighted in yellow.

[image]

However, once the plugin is exported as shown below, and placed as the jar in **\eclipse\plugins**, all the images are lost. What could be the reason for this?

[image]

After the jar is placed, the below is rendered without the images-

[image]

**MANIFEST.MF** file-

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse adds the compiled Java classes by default. Other files must be included manually in build.properties, example :icons or splash screen images.

A good example can be found here https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html

Hope it helps !